# jquery complex selector,How find all elements least those within an element with specific ID?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How I can I find all elements that are not within an element with specific ID?
i try this but it not work:

```
$(':not(#content *)')
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select everything, then use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove what you don't need:

```
$("*").not("#content *");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(':not([id="content"])')
```

Comment: This take all less the element with a content ID, but I want all items unless those within this

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

**html**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4">
        <div id="div5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(function(){

    var $divsWithoutContentParent = $('body div').filter(function(){
        return !$(this).closest('#content').length;
    });

    console.log($divsWithoutContentParent);
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTNhe/2/)